# Mailkit SearchQuery IMAP BAD Command Argument Error. 11

Tags: mailkit

Is there anything wrong with this query?

zSQry = SearchQuery.Seen.And(SearchQuery.SubjectContains("spain").And(SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(New Date(2017, 3, 11))))

I´m getting "BAD" from server

S: A00000005 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed.
C: A00000006 UID SEARCH CHARSET US-ASCII SEEN  SUBJECT spain SINCE 11-MAR-2017
S: A00000006 BAD Command Argument Error. 11
C: A00000007 LOGOUT
S: * BYE Microsoft Exchange Server 2016 IMAP4 server signing off.

Or this kind of search is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Oops my bad, a little mistake in my searchquery construct, but an interesting aspect to note, because there was no compilation error in VS2005.
This is the initial search query, nothing wrong with sintax at IDE, but produces an error at server
SearchQuery.Seen.And(SearchQuery.SubjectContains("paulistana").And(SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(New Date(2017, 3, 11))))

Now with a small change (parentesis in bold), it works perfect
SearchQuery.Seen.And(SearchQuery.SubjectContains("paulistana")**)**.And(SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(New Date(2017, 3, 11)))

First produces (double space between SEEN and SUBJECT)
C: A00000006 UID SEARCH CHARSET US-ASCII SEEN  SUBJECT spain SINCE 11-MAR-2017

Second produces (single space)
C: A00000006 UID SEARCH CHARSET US-ASCII SEEN SUBJECT spain SINCE 11-MAR-2017

Comment: That looks like a bug. Can you file an issue about this on github at https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit ? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an old version of MailKit? I can't reproduce this with 1.16.2.

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, hold on, it´s been a long time I'm using mailkit. Since 2015.
That´s why you can´t reproduce with current version. 
I´m on 1.2.12.0, so have to reconsider and upgrade.

I´ll check with current version.
No need to open an issue, thanks to refresh me.